# How to translate a 12-hour time into 24-hour in a batch command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I'm new to the batch command , recently I'm working on a batch script to get a file update time .

```
:GET_FILE_UPDATE_TIME

rem ****************************************
rem ** Get the modify time of the file
rem ****************************************
FOR %%f IN (%~1) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf

echo %~1 update time :%filedatetime%>>%OUT_DIR%\%CORREL_LOG_UPDATE_TIME%.txt

rem Get the file update time
set filehour=%filedatetime:~11,2%

REM below is to remove the 0 from the time , eg. 09AM change into 9AM 
SET /a filehour=1!filehour!-(11!filehour!-1!filehour!)/10
set filemins=%filedatetime:~14,2%
SET /a filemins=1!filemins!-(11!filemins!-1!filemins!)/10
set /A filetime=(%filehour%*60*60)+(%filemins%*60)

goto:eof
```

At first I think the script works fine, but then I found that there's a bug with it.
some files are returning a 12hour time format, such as follow.

> filedatetime=01/20/2014 07:12 PM

or below ( for AM )

> SET filedatetime=21/01/2014 07:52

or

> SET filedatetime=01/21/2014 05:08 AM

When doing the calculation, it's become 7:12 AM, while it actually 19:12 PM.

Could anyone please help how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to incorporate this into your code fairly easily, by changing variable names and the like.

```
set time=07:12 PM

if "%time%"=="%time:AM=%" set /a t=%time:~0,2%+12

if defined t set time=%t%%time:~2%

echo %time%
```

Given a variable following the convention `00:00 AM` / `PM` this will check if the time is *not* AM, if so it will convert to 24 hour time.

Comment: Thank you unclemeat.this looks working when it's PM , but when it's AM, it still add 12 hours,                                          C:\Users\abc>C:\Temp\test.bat

C:\Users\abc>set time=10:12 PM

C:\Users\abc>if "10:12 PM" == "10:12 PM" set /a t=10+12

C:\Users\abc>if defined t set time=22:12 PM

C:\Users\abc>echo 22:12 PM
22:12 PM

C:\Users\abc>C:\Temp\test.bat

C:\Users\abc>set time=10:12 AM

C:\Users\abc>if "10:12 AM" == "10:12 " set /a t=10+12

C:\Users\abc>if defined t set time=22:12 AM

C:\Users\abc>echo 22:12 AM
22:12 AM

Comment: sorry, but still got a problem when the test case like SET filedatetime=21/01/2014 07:52 

which means AM

Comment: Another problem - Hours of 8PM and 9PM will fail: 08+12 will yield an error because 08 will be interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED - Localization in output of dates usually leads to a nightmare when parsing is needed. Added code to try to sanitize the date and time. And no, no bulletproof, i have no access to all the possible localizations to test it. Some adjust may be needed.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    for %%f in ("%~f0") do call :get24HDateTime "%%~tf" dt 
    echo %dt%

    call :get24HDateTime "%date% 01:00 AM"
    call :get24HDateTime "%date% 01:00 PM"
    call :get24HDateTime "%date% 00:00 AM"
    call :get24HDateTime "%date% 23:00"
    call :get24HDateTime "%date% 07:00"

    endlocal

exit /b

:get24HDateTime "inputDateTime" outputVariable
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "input=%~1"
    set "DT="
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cmd /d /q /e:on /c "for %%f in ("%input: =" "%") do echo(%%~f"^|findstr /r /b /e /c:"[0-9/.-]*" /c:"[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" /c:"[AP]M"') do (
        set "DT=!DT! %%~a"
    )
    for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=A/: " %%a in ("%DT:PM= PM%") do (
        if not "%%f"=="PM" ( set "H=%%d" ) else ( set /a "H=(1%%d %% 100)+12" )
        set "DT=%%a/%%b/%%c !H!:%%e"
    )
    endlocal & if not "%~2"=="" ( set "%~2=%DT%" ) else echo(%DT%
    exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you MC. but it's still not working for call :get24HDateTime "%date% 01:00 PM"
it still return 01 , while we expect it return 13

Comment: @user3221750, Have you checked you are not reading the wrong line? for me it returns 13 not 01.

Comment: That's strange, I copy exactly the same your script and nothing been change, and I got below returnC:\Users\abc>C:\Temp\test.bat
2014/01/23 周四:01
2014/01/23 周四:01
2014/01/23 周四:00
2014/01/23 周四:23
2014/01/23 周四:07

Comment: @user3221750, it seems your %date% variable is including the weekday. I've updated the answer to "handle" it. But probably you will have to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%x IN ("01/20/2014 07:12" "01/20/2014 3:22" "01/20/2014 17:12" "21/01/2014 07:52" "01/21/2014 05:08") DO (
 SET "filedatetime=%%~x"
 CALL :gfutq
 CALL ECHO produces %%filedatetime%% and filetime=%%filetime%% and filetimez=%%filetimez%%
 SET "filedatetime=%%~x AM"
 CALL :gfutq
 CALL ECHO produces %%filedatetime%% and filetime=%%filetime%% and filetimez=%%filetimez%%
 SET "filedatetime=%%~x PM"
 CALL :gfutq
 CALL ECHO produces %%filedatetime%% and filetime=%%filetime%% and filetimez=%%filetimez%%
)
GOTO :EOF
:GET_FILE_UPDATE_TIME

rem ****************************************
rem ** Get the modify time of the file
rem ****************************************
FOR %%f IN (%~1) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf

echo %~1 update time :%filedatetime%>>%OUT_DIR%\%CORREL_LOG_UPDATE_TIME%.txt

:gfutq

ECHO original filedatetime=%filedatetime%

SET "filetimez="
SET "f1224="
:: first - have we got "AM" or "PM" as last 2 characters?
IF "%filedatetime:~-2%"=="AM" SET /a f1224=0
IF "%filedatetime:~-2%"=="PM" SET /a f1224=12
IF DEFINED F1224 SET "filedatetime=%filedatetime:~0,-3%"
:: last 2 characters=minutes, make decimal
set /a filemins=1%filedatetime:~-2% -100
SET "filedatetime=%filedatetime:~0,-3%"
:: last 2 characters=hour
set "filehour=%filedatetime:~-2%"
SET "filedatetime=%filedatetime:~0,-2%"
SET "filedatetime=%filedatetime: =%"
:: ensure leading spaces are made 0 (in case of leading-zero suppression)
:: prefix the result with 1 and subtract 100 giving decimal hours
set /a filehour=1%filehour: =0%-100
:: no suffix found?
IF NOT DEFINED F1224 GOTO gfutns
:: 12-hour clock in use; if 12:?? make 0:?? then add 0 or 12
IF %filehour% gtr 12 SET filetime=makes no sense&GOTO :EOF
IF %filehour%==12 (SET /a filehour=%f1224%) ELSE (SET /a filehour+=%f1224%)
IF %filehour% gtr 24 SET filetime=makes no sense&GOTO :EOF

:gfutns
set /A filetime=(%filehour%*60*60)+(%filemins%*60)
SET filemins=0%filemins%
SET filehour=0%filehour%
SET filetimez=%filehour:~-2%%filemins:~-2%

goto:eof
```

Here's a little demonstration that should deal with all of the situations.

I've arbitrarily defined times 13:??+ as making no sense if they are followed by `AM` or `PM`.

Numbers returned are the seconds-since-midnight calculation and zero-filled hhmm. the `filedatetime` is returned with the time elements removed.

Note that I'm using a different entry to the routine as I've set the required datetime string from test values.